# Send text file over http in android

Tags: java, android, http, servlets

Currently, I send a username as a parameter to my servlet from the android application.Now I want to send text file to my servlet from the android application.It is possible?.
Here sample code i tried for send a username over Http.

```
      try
         {
       URL url = new URL("http:/xx.xxx.xxx.x/sample?user=admin"); // File as parameter 
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
             BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
             String x = "";
             String total = "";
             int i=0;
             ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList();
             while((x = r.readLine()) != null)
             {
                         content.add(x);

             }
             in.close();
             r.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
             Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
```

Above code works fine,How to pass text file which stored in my SD card as a parameter to the servlet?.thanks in advance.

Comment: ya is possible we can send file to server please refer follwing link      http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/

Comment: instead of image place your text file

Answer (score 0):

Here some code, but I strongly recommend to upload data through POST request instead of GET request:

```
private void sendFileThroughHTTP(File file) {
    try {
        Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("http").encodedAuthority("xx.xxx.xxx.x")
                .path("sample")
                .appendQueryParameter("user", "admin")
                .appendQueryParameter("file", fileToString(file))
                .build();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri.toString());

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.execute(get);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e("SOME_TAG", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("SOME_TAG", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}

private String fileToString(File file) {
    String resultString = "";
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    if (file != null && file.isFile()) {
        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String temp;
            while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(temp);
            }
            resultString = stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("SOME_TAG", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("SOME_TAG", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fileReader != null) {
                    fileReader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("SOME_TAG", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
        }
    }
    return resultString;
}
```